# Merging two datasets with different date formats and different lengths in R

Tags: r, dplyr, merge

Hopefully somebody can help me out. I have two datasets:

1. The first has *daily* radiation values over a ten year period, for 30 counties, e.g:

```
   PLACE      DATE        DATA
   <chr>      <date>     <dbl>
1 BEAVER     1951-01-28     0
2 BOX ELDER1 1951-01-28     0
3 BOX ELDER2 1951-01-28     0
4 CACHE      1951-01-28     0
5 CARBON     1951-01-28     0
6 DAGGETT    1951-01-28     0
```

2. The second has *annual* cancer values over the same period, for the same 30 counties, e.g.:

```
   PLACE Cancer_Deaths year
1 BEAVER             4 1946
2 BEAVER             3 1947
3 BEAVER             6 1948
4 BEAVER             5 1949
5 BEAVER             2 1950
6 BEAVER             7 1951
```

What I want to do is merge them into the same dataset.

I've had a look around the site, but can't seem to find a solution that fits what I'm trying to do.

I *think* the steps I should be taking are:

- converting the year column to a yearmonthday column...
- getting the annual values for each place to then fill each daily row
- then merging them on the basis of date

But I'm having a bit of trouble getting this to work. Any help hugely appreciated!

Comment: Start with  `merge(df1, df2, by = 'PLACE')`

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach given I got what you mean correctly. Lets call your two tables as df1 and df2.

```
df1
   PLACE      DATE        DATA
1 BEAVER     1951-01-28     0
2 BOX ELDER1 1951-01-28     0
3 BOX ELDER2 1951-01-28     0
4 CACHE      1951-01-28     0
5 CARBON     1951-01-28     0
6 DAGGETT    1951-01-28     0
```

```
df2
   PLACE Cancer_Deaths year
1 BEAVER             4 1946
2 BEAVER             3 1947
3 BEAVER             6 1948
4 BEAVER             5 1949
5 BEAVER             2 1950
6 BEAVER             7 1951
```

1. In df1 *daily radiation*, extract *year* from column *DATE* using *year()* from package *lubridate*

```
library(lubridate)
df1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(year = lubridate::year(Date))

  PLACE      DATE        DATA  year
  <chr>      <date>     <dbl> <dbl>
1 BEAVER     1951-01-28     0  1951
2 BOX ELDER1 1951-01-28     0  1951
3 BOX ELDER2 1951-01-28     0  1951
4 CACHE      1951-01-28     0  1951
5 CARBON     1951-01-28     0  1951
6 DAGGETT    1951-01-28     0  1951
```

2. Then use *left_join* from *dplyr* package to merge df1 and df2 with both keys *PLACE* and *year* from both tables.

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(df1, df2, by=c("PLACE", "year"))

  PLACE    DATE        DATA  year Cancer_Deaths
  <chr>    <date>     <dbl> <dbl>         <dbl>
1 BEAVER   1951-01-28     0  1951             7
2 BOX ELD~ 1951-01-28     0  1951            NA
3 BOX ELD~ 1951-01-28     0  1951            NA
4 CACHE    1951-01-28     0  1951            NA
5 CARBON   1951-01-28     0  1951            NA
6 DAGGETT  1951-01-28     0  1951            NA
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the merge command as follows:

```
total <- merge(daily_radiation_data_frame_name,cancer_data_frame_name,by="PLACE")
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! Should be able to get there now. 